# Python Network Socket - [WinError 10053]

Tags: python, sockets, networking, virtual-machine

I am trying to write a pretty straightforward "network socket" (server) program and "network connect" (client) program based off of a course I am taking. I am getting a [WinError 10053] when trying to connect using the "network connect" program from a Kali Linux virtual machine in VMWare Workstation 15. The Kali VM network adapter is running in NAT mode.

[Host Computer ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xalPC.png)

[Kali VM ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7jGm.png)

Server

```
import socket

SRV_ADDR = input("Type the server IP address: ")
SRV_PORT = int(input("Type the server port: "))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((SRV_ADDR, SRV_PORT))
s.listen(1)
print("Server started! Waiting for connections...")
connection, address = s.accept()
print('Client connected with address:', address)
while 1:
    data = connection.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    connection.sendall(b'-- Message Received --\n')
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
connection.close()
```

Client

```
import socket

SER_ADDR = input("Type the server IP address: ")
SER_PORT = int(input("Type the server port: "))

s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2.connect((SER_ADDR, SER_PORT))
print("Connection Established")

message = input("Message to send: ")
s2.sendall(message.encode())
s2.close()
```

When I run the "network socket" program from my local computer I can connect successfully from the Kali VM using Netcat, and send data.

[Successful - Server Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TT9L.png)

[Successful - Client Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW18F.png)

If I try to run the "network connect" program from Kali, I successfully connect, but when I send data I get the WinError 10053 and a reference to line 13 in the "network connect" program.

[Failure - Server Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cnR0.png)

[Failure - Client Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEUg8.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if this is not posted correctly, it's my first time posting to a forum :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after the client sends his message to the server, he closes his socket, but the server still tries to receive data.

If you are planning to send only 1 message, then you should remove the loop from the server's code.

Otherwise, you can wrap the `recv` line in the server by try/except, to handle this situation.